# How to change the Play Store language?

Tags: google-play-store, languages

I live in Hong Kong, and the Play Store displays everything in the local Cantonese language.
I have set everything I can (Android language, Account language, even the app locale via Xposed Module "App Settings") to English, but I still see all the categories in the store in Chinese. Can someone help me change those to English?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Play Store also uses IP address to check the location, though I'm not sure if it also affects in-app language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short answer: You can't!

From [How can I switch language in google play?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592231/3622940), you used to be able to work around this via a proxy:

> Basically the market is determined automatically based on your IP. You can change some local country settings from your Gmail account settings but still IP of the country you're browsing from is more important. To go around it you'd have to Proxy-cheat. Check out some ways/sites: http://www.affilorama.com/forum/market-research/how-to-change-country-search-settings-in-google-t4160.html

For the current versions of Google Play, it will **always** go for your IP address and geo-ify it. Therefore, if you're really determined you can use [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to route through some servers with Geo-IPs.

If VPNs are not a solution for you (They weren't mine: Too expensive, too risky and depends on trust of the host, ...) you can mess with a GeoIP database (and have Hong Kong become US), alike as [this XKCD comic](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/geoip.png):

[image]

### Now what?

If you're a fan of Google products and want to keep using it, you will have to deal with it, or [use the web based market as pointed out in another answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/87642/71473). What I did instead was that I rooted my phone to remove Google Play store after installing Amazon app store, and used it instead.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: I haven't seen any credible sources stating otherwise, so until someone shows me some, probably yes @FrazerKirkman

Comment: Aug 2020, Still not fixed. 
I get the Swedish language for my movie descriptions. Everything else in Google is English (including language account settings) and I live in Denmark (which is not the capitol of Sweden :) )

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be head over to your Google account and change the Language settings to something you preferred. Once done open the device head over to settings>application manager>Clear the cache and the data stored by the Google play Store and close the app. Once done, try opening the Google PlayStore and this time the language will be changed.

Comment: That's what I tried already, it did not work.

Comment: Well, that's something weird,do one thing create new Google account over web and upon registration select UK/US as country and then again try putting that google account over your device and yes remove the older one and then see if you can see any difference ?? Anyway one more thing which device you are experiencing problem with?

Comment: I have two devices, same issue, once HTC One M8 and once old Samsung Galaxy note

Comment: No, problem at all you can put the new gmail account created over both of the the device ! Try doing that and see if it can be of any use !