# Why did my Google Play store switch to Chinese?

Tags: motorola-moto-g2

I tried to update an app, and all of a sudden my Google Play Store switched from English to Cantonese. I'm in New Zealand, and my ip address--according to whereisip.net--appears to be California. 
What the heck is going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the Play store language](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87626/how-to-change-the-play-store-language)